QBO connection to PBI
I am trying to connect my accounting firm's QuickBooks Online account to Power BI for analytics. I have the ODBC driver installed, but when I load data, I either get data that is incomplete to the current period or I get errors when loading the tables.
ODBC Driver used:
https://quickbooks.intuit.com/app/apps/appdetails/qodbc_for_quickbooks_online/en-us/
Has anyone successfully built this connection and can advise on how I can troubleshoot and fix the issues?
Ben
